# AttributeError: module 'keras.src.backend' has no attribute 'Variable' with Dropout layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to re-use a neural network for sound classification but keras give an error:
AttributeError: module 'keras.src.backend' has no attribute 'Variable'.
May it be a compatibility problem?
I'm using keras v3.0.5.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
# from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn import metrics 
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import keras
from keras import backend

num_labels = yy.shape[1]
filter_size = 2

# Construct model 
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(40,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(num_labels))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()
```

According to Keras documentation, if I use a dropout layer:

```
layers.Dropout(0.5, noise_shape=None, seed=None),
```

it gives the same error.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace to your question

Comment: do you have a backend configured?  if not it will never import the Variable class which might have something to do with your error.

Comment: check out this link: https://keras.io/getting_started/#:~:text=keras%3D%3D2.15.-,Configuring%20your%20backend,-You%20can%20export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a backend configured before you import keras.  If not, it will never import the Variable class which might have something to do with your error. **Put your setting of the backend type before importing ANY of the keras modules.**

Info on how to configure the backend can be found on this page:
https://keras.io/getting_started/

Copied from that page:

> You can export the environment variable KERAS_BACKEND or you can edit
> your local config file at ~/.keras/keras.json to configure your
> backend. Available backend options are: "jax", "tensorflow", "torch".
> Example:

```
export KERAS_BACKEND="jax"
```

> In Colab, you can do:

```
import os 
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "jax" 
import keras
```

> Note: The
> backend must be configured before importing Keras, and the backend
> cannot be changed after the package has been imported.

Comment: Hi thak you for your replies! It seems your suggestions solve my problem!

Comment: Please accept my answer as the correct one by selecting the check mark next to the answer.  Thanks.