# AttributeError: module 'keras.src.backend' has no attribute 'Variable'

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Could you please help me troubleshoot the following error occurring in the code?
The error occurred while attempting to implement learning using LGBM.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "jax"
import keras
data = result
target = data['close'].values

features = data[['diff_log_close', 'diff_log_open', 'diff_log_high', 'diff_log_low']].values

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
features_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(features)
target_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(target.reshape(-1, 1))

def create_dataset(X, y, time_steps=1):
    Xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(len(X) - time_steps):
        v = X[i:(i + time_steps)]
        Xs.append(v)
        ys.append(y[i + time_steps])
    return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)

TIME_STEPS = 10  # Number of time steps to input to LSTM
X, y = create_dataset(features_scaled, target_scaled, TIME_STEPS)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_pred_inv = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
y_test_inv = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))

for i in range(len(y_pred_inv)):
    print(f"prediction: {y_pred_inv[i][0]}, value: {y_test_inv[i][0]}")
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.src.backend' has no attribute 'Variable'
```

I changed the version of Keras.

Here is the detailed error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[84], line 42
     40 # LSTMモデルの構築
     41 model = Sequential()
---> 42 model.add(LSTM(units=50, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
     43 model.add(Dense(units=1))
     44 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

File ~/work/bakueki/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/lstm.py:460, in LSTM.__init__(self, units, activation, recurrent_activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, recurrent_initializer, bias_initializer, unit_forget_bias, kernel_regularizer, recurrent_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, recurrent_constraint, bias_constraint, dropout, recurrent_dropout, seed, return_sequences, return_state, go_backwards, stateful, unroll, **kwargs)
    433 def __init__(
    434     self,
    435     units,
   (...)
    458     **kwargs,
    459 ):
--> 460     cell = LSTMCell(
    461         units,
    462         activation=activation,
    463         recurrent_activation=recurrent_activation,
    464         use_bias=use_bias,
    465         kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
    466         unit_forget_bias=unit_forget_bias,
    467         recurrent_initializer=recurrent_initializer,
    468         bias_initializer=bias_initializer,
...
     73     trainable=False,
     74     name="seed_generator_state",
     75 )

AttributeError: module 'keras.src.backend' has no attribute 'Variable'
```

This error occurred while trying to build an LSTM model.

Comment: This code does not refer to anything named `Variable`, therefore the error must be happening elsewhere, in some other code that you have not shown us.  It is very hard to help when you do not show us the code where the actual error happens.  Please update the question and add the full error traceback message, so we can see where the error actually occurs.

Comment: I had answered this but a moderator  removed it as a duplicate (I did post almost (but not identical answer is the environment variable must be set BEFORE any of the keras modules are imported.   @Tombolo s code imports some keras modules before setting it.

Comment: @JohnGordon You are correct it is happening somewhere else its because the environment variable was not set early enough in his module and some keras setup wound up being skipped.  later on it caused the error he experienced.

Comment: the relevant section from my original post here:  You need to have a backend configured before you import keras. If not, it will never import the Variable class which might have something to do with your error. Put your setting of the backend type before importing ANY of the keras modules. you import a few in your code before you set it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78173150/attributeerror-module-keras-src-backend-has-no-attribute-variable-with-drop/78173226#78173226